# Handling sums of correlated random variables with a directed path structure

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

Recently, I've been seeing random variables with the following correlation structure based on directed paths on a graph. For example, there are $16$ directed paths "directed downwards from the peak" reaching the $n=4$ steps row in the following image:
[image]

For each edge $e$ of the graph, assign a random variable $X_e$. These $X_e$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli, taking on the value $1$ with probability $1-q$ and the value $-1$ with probability $q$. I'm generally considering $q$ relatively small but independent of graph properties, such as $q=.1$, say, and in general $q<1/2$. Thus with high probability a plurality of the $X_e$ are $1$.

For a directed path $P$ starting at the top and ending at the bottom row of this graph, I assign the value $\prod_{e \in P} X_e $; i.e. the "value" of a path is the product of the edges. My interest is in the probability that the sum of the values of the paths $P$ are positive, i.e. $\mathbb{P}\left[\sum_{P} \prod_{e \in P} X_e >0\right]$, in the limit that the graph becomes "large" at a fixed small $q$.

For example, consider a family of the graph above where the bottom row is $n$ directed steps from the peak, then I am curious about

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\left[\sum_{P \in P_n} \prod_{e \in P} X_e >0\right] \rightarrow ?$$

where $P_n$ refers to the set of directed paths from the "peak" to the row $n$ steps below.

The reason I am interested in this is because I believe (depending on the type of graph) there exists $q_c$ where for $q<q_c$ the limiting probability above is $1$, while for $q_c < q < 1/2$ the limiting probability is $1/2$.

In particular, I am tempted that for my $2d$ graph above $q_c=0$ while for a $3d$ graph with four possible directed steps at each vertex $q_c >0$.

---

The above is the background to my problem. My first question is: Does such a problem have a name? I suspect it may have been studied before.

My second is, are there tools for studying whether the probability goes to $1$ or $1/2$?

---

For the case of the probability going to $1$, I was considering using $P(\sum_{P \in P_n} \prod_{e \in P} X_e  < 0) \leq P(\sum_{P \in P_n} |\prod_{e \in P} X_e - \mu | < \mu) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[|\sum_{P \in P_n} \prod_{e \in P} X_e - \mu|^k]}{\mu^k}$ where $\mu = \mathbb{E}[\sum_{P \in P_n} \prod_{e \in P} X_e ] = (2 (1-2q))^n$. For the graph above, the second moment is intimately related to the probability that two simple $1d$ random walks collide after $k$ steps, and the fourth moment has a similar combinatorial interpretation. However, these calculations quickly become somewhat tedious.